# Asynchronous update on UI windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I read about how to update page UI asynchronously on internet and got that we can update page UI by calling dispatcher and invoking method like

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   MessageBox.Show("some message");
});
```

But, it is not working.I think that I am missing some conceptual basics.
I want update status textbox with respect to phone's internet connectivity.

```
async void HomePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (App.Connectivity == -1)
    {
        await ConnectionInitialization();
    }
}

private async Task ConnectionInitialization()
{
    if(NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    {
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => SetProgressIndicator(true));
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => TextBoxAppStatus.Text = "Connecting...");
    } 
    else
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => TextBoxAppStatus.Text = "Disconnected");
        await ConnectionInitialization();
    }
}
```

Here, it gets into infinite loop, without displaying anything on the screen, neither progress bar nor textbox. Please tell me where I am conceptually wrong. 
I will be highly thankful,if you can also provide me resources for making User friendly stud app.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have infinite recursion if no connection available

About threads: if you use `async` on UI, code execution continues on UI thread, so you don't need to use `Dispatcher`

Use `DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged` event to track changes in connection status.